Texturize Terrain Model with Images
I am new to Blender.I am trying to texturize terrain model in DXF format with Ortho rectified image. The terrain model is a triangle mesh.
I run into a problem with displaying the dxf file in Blender so i exported the dxf to OBJ in Microstation.
Then I imported the OBJ to Blender and tried to add the image as texture (Material>Base Color>Image Texture) which did not work.The dimensions of the image is bigger than the terrain model. Is there any other way?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
